# Multiple applications separated with Angular modules

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

I am in the process of starting a new big project involving Angular5+ and using Angular-cli as a start.
The plan is to build 10+ smaller applications that will be spread out on sites in a CMS. 
I planned to implement Lazy-loading of the modules, so based on the URL, I will specify what module will be bootstrapped.

My first idea is to build them in separate Modules so each application gets its own Module.
If this is the best way to do it, how would I approach routing? I want each Module (application) to have its own routing separated from the other Modules.

My second question is, is this the best way to do it? Anyone done something similar using another method?

Comment: The Angular docs on modules include discussion of routing patterns: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [`nx`](https://github.com/nrwl/nx), by the guys from [`nrwl`](https://nrwl.io/nx).

> The big feature of Nx is its ability to set up and orchestrate a workspace for our application domain. Extending the power of the AngularCLI, Nx can handle setting up an AngularCLI project in an Nx Workspace format, with support for multiple Angular applications and shared libs.

The nx was founded by ex googlers, Jeff Cross and Victor Savkin, who both were a part of angular core team, and helped build many of its core features (like router or forms).